# includeExceptionDetailInFaults=true works in dev-environment, but not in test-environment

Tags: c#, wcf, service, configuration

I have a WCF service and set

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
```

This works well when I start the server in Visual Studio on my developer machine. But it doesn't work at our test server.

Config snippet:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>      
    <behavior name="debug">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"  />          
    </behavior>        
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name ="TisCalc.Service.UCLCalc" behaviorConfiguration="debug"></service>
</services>
```

and when a client calls the server with an invalid request I get a fault like this (this is what I want)

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="de-DE">Fehler beim Deserialisieren des Textkörpers der Anforderungsnachricht für Vorgang "Angebot".</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
               <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
               <InnerException>
                  <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
                  <InnerException>
                     <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
                     <InnerException i:nil="true"/>
                     <Message>Instanzvalidierungsfehler: 'AT' ist kein gültiger Wert für Land.</Message>
                     <StackTrace>bei Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderUCLCalcInterface.Read13_Land(String s)
   bei Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderUCLCalcInterface.Read14_Adresse(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   bei Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderUCLCalcInterface.Read15_Leasinggeber(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   bei Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderUCLCalcInterface.Read16_AngebotContext(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   bei Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderUCLCalcInterface.Read33_Item()
   bei Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
   bei System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)</StackTrace>
                     <Type>System.InvalidOperationException</Type>
                  </InnerException>
                  <Message>Fehler im XML-Dokument (20,13).</Message>
                  <StackTrace>bei System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   bei System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, XmlSerializer serializer, MessagePartDescription returnPart, MessagePartDescriptionCollection bodyParts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)</StackTrace>
                  <Type>System.InvalidOperationException</Type>
               </InnerException>
               <Message>Fehler beim Deserialisieren des Textkörpers der Anforderungsnachricht für Vorgang "Angebot".</Message>
               <StackTrace><![CDATA[bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, XmlSerializer serializer, MessagePartDescription returnPart, MessagePartDescriptionCollection bodyParts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)]]></StackTrace>
               <Type>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException</Type>
            </ExceptionDetail>
         </detail>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Same call against the test environment with exactly the same service configuration and same sources returns this error 500, and I absolutely don't know why...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
      <title>500 - Internal server error.</title>
      <style type="text/css">
         <!--body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}-->
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="header">
         <h1>Server Error</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
         <div class="content-container">
            <fieldset>
               <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
               <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
            </fieldset>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Is there any config I have to do in IIS? I hope someone can give me a hint.

edited: additional info:
Usually i throw a `Faultexception` with strongly typed Details. 
But I don't want to write a handler for requests which don't match the contract and causing an error during deserialization. for example, if a Client (like in my test request) sends an invalid `enum-value`. 
In this case i want the "free" debuginformations. In production, such invalid requests won't happen. So we can turn off  `includeExceptionDetailInFaults` in production environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true` Instead, You need to throw [`FaultException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). And it is also recommended that you use the [`FaultContractAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultcontractattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to design your services to return ***strongly-typed*** SOAP faults.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! Usually i throw a Faultexception with strongly typed Details. 
But I don't want to write a handler for requests which don't match the contract and causing an error during deserialization. for example, if a Client (like in my testrequest) sends an invalid enum-value. 
In this case i want the "free" debuginformations. In production, such invalid requests won't happen. So we can turn off  includeExceptionDetailInFaults in production environment.


*edited because i pressed enter instead of shift+enter... :/

Comment: @Mike try to remove the name of your service behavior and make a test to check if it is really affecting your endpoint service.
The config tag <behavior name="debug"> must be <behavior>

Comment: @Ricardo I removed the name-attribute 
<behavior>
and behaviorConfiguration-Attribute
<service name ="TisCalc.Service.UCLCalc"></service>
and recycled the apppool.

no changes :/ I still get Error 500. seems like my settings have no effect.

Comment: @Mike looks like your IIS is blocking the full message and sending a generic error 500. Try to enable detailed errors within IIS.
Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager > Your Web > Error Pages > properties and select Detail errors